# haben + zu + Infinitiv vs. müssen

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference, word-choice, meaning-in-context

Was ist der Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen Ausdrücke nach dem Muster (haben + zu + Infinitiv) und Formulierungen mit dem Modalverb (müssen)? Also, gibt es praktisch irgendwelche Nuancen in der Bedeutung, Anwendungen oder Kontext? Wann wird was verwendet?

> **z.B**.
>   Jeder Student hat dieses Praktikum abzuleisten.
>   Jeder Student muss dieses Praktikum ableisten.

Comment: Related: [Must vs. need to vs. have to](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/22830/9551)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ja. *Haben zu* wird vor allem für Vorschriften verwendet, *müssen* ist breitbandiger. *Müssen* wird sowohl für Vorschriften als auch objektive Notwendigkeiten verwendet:

> Ich muss schlafen.

Hier bleibt unklar, ob einem vorgeschrieben wird, zu schlafen, oder ob man sehr müde ist und deshalb nicht mehr wach bleiben kann. *Haben zu* jedoch vor allem für Vorschriften:

> Ich habe zu schlafen. (jemand schreibt es mir vor)

*Haben zu* ist zudem *deutlich* schärfer als *müssen*:

> Sie haben den Text bis heute Abend fertigzustellen.

Wenn man dies in einer Mail vom Chef liest, weiß man, dass Feuer unterm Dach ist - oder er generell nicht gut mit Leuten umspringt.

Im Falle der allgemeinen Anweisung an alle Studenten ist das aber gebräuchlich.

Es existiert noch eine Passivkonverse *sein zu*:

> Das Praktikum ist bis zum Ende des Semesters abzuleisten.

Auch dies ist sehr üblich für allgemein gehaltene Vorschriften.