# "Ich habe zu..." is old or wrong?

Tags: verb-usage

I'm an English native-speaker. Somehow I've got the construction "Ich habe zu..." in my mind and I don't know if it's correct. zB: *Ich habe zu gehen* or *Ich habe zu beichten.* It seems old or formal for "I am obliged (I must) to leave." And "I am obliged to confess." Is this something arcane or just plain wrong?

Comment: It is well-formed German, but, as you say, a little bit stiff and outdated. Usually you would say *Ich muss...*. - In more formal written communication it can still be met, but then the sentences are quite more complex than your examples.

Comment: Please check:
https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24465/haben-zu-infinitiv-vs-m%C3%BCssen
https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22830/must-vs-need-to-vs-have-to

Comment: In der Form "ich hab' zu arbeiten" ist nichts veraltetes oder hochnäsiges, sondern ist es gängige Sprachpraxis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's contemporary German to use **haben zu** as a variation for **müssen**. The tricky part is, it's a mild alternative if you are the one who must act:

> Ich habe noch zu tun. *(asks for understanding)* — Ich muss noch etwas tun. *(dismissive)*
>
> Ich habe zu danken. *(glad)* — Ich muss ihnen danken. *(subordinative)*

And a harsh alternative if someone else must act, in your view:

> Er hat einzusehen, dass … *(harsh)* — Er muss einsehen, dass … *(sympathetic)*
>
> Sie haben zuzugeben, dass … *(harsh)* — Sie müssen zugeben, dass … *(sympathetic)*

---

Your examples:

> Ich habe zu gehen. *(asks for sympathy)* — Ich muss gehen. *(plain or dismissive)*
>
> Ich habe zu beichten. *(asks for sympathy)* — Ich muss beichten. *(plain or dismissive)*

Comment: Problematisch is when you say "Du hast zu gehen," but it sounds like "Du hasst zu gehen."